# Issue with document deletion using Firebase and Typescript (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Upon clicking "Delete AAP", the code is supposed to delete the associated document from my Firebase collection, but for some reason it deletes the document, then uploads it again (without calling the function that uploads the document).

The weird part is that it will only work if manually refresh the page. If I upload a document, and attempt to delete it straight away, it starts bugging out.

I have omitted unrelated parts of the component.

([I'm using errors to show what happens in this screenshot when I click the delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uGNL.png))

```
    const [AAP, setAAP] = useState<string>();
    const [newAAP, setNewAAP] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const [noAAP, setNoAAP] = useState(false);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState<{ error: boolean; msg: string }[]>([]);

    const { userDetails } = useMyUserDetails();

    // Create a ref for the alert
    const alertRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const userRef = doc(db, "users", lastSegment);
        onSnapshot(userRef, (docSnap) => {
            if (docSnap.exists()) {
                const userData = docSnap.data() as ProfileDetails;
                setAAP(userData.aap);
                setNoAAP(false);
            } else {
                setNoAAP(true);
            }
        });
    }, [lastSegment]);

    const displayAAP = () => {
        if (AAP && !noAAP) {
            return (
                <div id="documents-uploaded">
                    <FileLink
                        className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-doc-upl"
                        docRef={AAP}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    // Handle document upload input change
    const handleAAPUpload = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.files != null) {
            const selectedFiles = Array.from(e.target.files);
            setNewAAP(selectedFiles);
        }
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (newAAP.length === 1 && userDetails) {
            const userRef = doc(db, "users", lastSegment);
            const URLs: string[] = convertFilesToURL(newAAP);
            const storage = getStorage();
            const storageRef = ref(storage, AAP);
            onSnapshot(userRef, (docSnap) => {
                if (docSnap.exists()) {
                    deleteObject(storageRef)
                        .then(() => {
                            setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                                ...prevErrors,
                                {
                                    error: false,
                                    msg: "AAP successfully updated",
                                },
                            ]);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    void updateDoc(userRef, {
                        aap: URLs[0],
                    });
                } else {
                    handleAAPSubmission({
                        e,
                        studentEmail: userDetails.primary_email,
                        studentName: userDetails.name,
                        studentId: userDetails.id,
                        documents: newAAP,
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                                ...prevErrors,
                                {
                                    error: false,
                                    msg: "AAP successfully uploaded",
                                },
                            ]);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                                ...prevErrors,
                                { error: true, msg: "Unsuccessful upload" },
                            ]);
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
            });
        } else if (newAAP.length !== 1) {
            setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                ...prevErrors,
                { error: true, msg: "Only one AAP document may be uploaded" },
            ]);
        }
        setErrors([]);
        setNewAAP([]);
    };

    const deleteAAP = () => {
        const AAPRef = doc(db, "users", lastSegment);
        const storage = getStorage();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, AAP);
        deleteObject(storageRef)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Deleted");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        deleteDoc(AAPRef)
            .then(() => {
                setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                    ...prevErrors,
                    { error: false, msg: "AAP successfully deleted" },
                ]);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setErrors((prevErrors) => [
                    ...prevErrors,
                    { error: true, msg: "Unable to delete AAP" },
                ]);
                console.log(error);
            });
        setNoAAP(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="settings-component">
                {!noAAP && <h4>My AAP files:</h4>}
                {noAAP && <h4>No AAP files</h4>}
                {!noAAP && (
                    <div>
                        {displayAAP()}
                        <Button onClick={deleteAAP}>Delete AAP</Button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            <div>
                <Form id="submit-form" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group
                        className="mb-3"
                        controlId="documents"
                        id="submit-documents"
                    >
                        {noAAP && <h4>Upload AAP</h4>}
                        {!noAAP && <h4>Update AAP</h4>}
                        <Form.Control
                            type="file"
                            onChange={handleAAPUpload}
                            className="submit-form-bubble"
                        />
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            id="request-form-submit"
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here is the function that updates the firebase storage :

```
// Interface for the properties of the handleSubmitRequest function
interface HandleAAPSubmissionProps {
    e: FormEvent;
    studentId: number;
    studentName: string;
    studentEmail: string;
    documents: File[];
}

// Function to handle the submission of a request
export const handleAAPSubmission = async ({
    e,
    studentId,
    studentName,
    studentEmail,
    documents,
}: HandleAAPSubmissionProps) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        // Add a new document to the 'users' collection
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", studentId.toString()), {
            studentId: studentId,
            studentName: studentName,
            studentEmail: studentEmail,
                        dateUploaded: serverTimestamp(),
            aap:
                documents.length > 0 ? (convertFilesToURL(documents))[0] : [],
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

I have tried many things, including changing the Form element to a basic JSX input element, and resetting the input element by using a state key, but nothing works.